# Obtaining 2 Different results from same column different WHERE in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME) AS NAMEA
FROM (DATA.1 WHERE MARKS > 50), COUNT(NAME) AS NAMEB FROM DATA.1
```

After running it I get this

> Syntax error in JOIN operation

I am trying to get the percentage of student pass, no. of student pass, total no. of student and no. of student fail.

Please help me to find whats wrong in the above Query.

please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially running two queries in one.

Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME) AS NAMEA
FROM DATA1
WHERE MARKS > 50
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME) AS NAMEB
FROM DATA1
```

If you want both columns in the same query then you would have to use a SUM of a CASE WHEN for the first query.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MARKS > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NAMEA,
       COUNT(NAME) AS NAMEB
FROM DATA1
```

For the rest of your points you would need the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME) AS TOTAL_STUDENTS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MARKS > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS STUDENTS_PASSED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MARKS > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(NAME) AS PASS_RATE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MARKS < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS STUDENTS_FAILED
FROM DATA1
```

Bear in mind that this missed out students that have exactly 50 marks. If 50 is a pass then you would need to use **>= 50** for STUDENTS_PASSED. If 50 is a fail then you would need to use **<= 50** for STUDENTS_FAILED.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got upvote when it was the second answer, and won't produce the OP expected output.

Comment: @sincere that would count students with a mark of 50 as passed.

Comment: @Moogle i mean this sorry
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM(CASE WHEN MARKS= 50  then 1 end)'.

Comment: @sincere there was a comma missing after TOTAL_STUDENTS. Try it again now.

Comment: I think is becos its java thats why case function cant be use